# How to connect to a SOAP/WSDL Web Services?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

i am implementing a SOAP/WSDL Web Services.

i am trying to use the `Service s = Service.create()` Routine but it does not connect to the Server. 
So is there another way to connect to a SOAP/WSDL Web Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to make client using wsimport.

It will create the necessary stubs to call the servce.

If you are doing this just for testing you can use soapUI.

Answer (score 0):

**I would suggest soapUI**

1. Download SoapUI from web (just download SoapUI, no need of SoapUI PRO)
2. click on file and select "New soapUI Project"
3. Give any project name and enter WSDL url ( note that webservice url should be followed by "?wsdl" )
4. It will load the wsdl for you, next enter required parameters in request
5. click on play button (Green button, next to webservice url), you will get response in right hand side panel

I hope this will help you